# How to create a Windows VM in GCP such that we can use it in Jenkins for automated tests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking for a help on GCP where I want to create a Windows VM and which will have Java and some browsers like say Chrome. Once this is done I wanted to integrate this VM to Jenkins such that whenever a automated build runs in Jenkins it will run those automated tests say Selenium on VM machine and creates the reports and so on. Is it possible via GCP. Please let me know and guide me on this and please share any tutorial for sample.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the images provided by GCP have that software installed, I mean you need to install manually or you can use [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to automate some of this task,
this is a quick information to get you started:

- Create [Windows Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances)
- Install [java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml) or [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-A7E27B90-A28D-4237-9383-A58B416071CA)
- Install [chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)
- Install [jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/download/)
- Automate the task with [jenkins and windows](https://hodgkins.io/automating-with-jenkins-and-powershell-on-windows-part-1)

As alternative you can deploy from [Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace), find the Jenkis which is installed on a Windows VM and then install the other components(chrome & java)
considers that some marketplace solutions has an additional cost

Comment: thanks am able to do it now after a long gap finally :)